# Make OLE Object cover whole page(including header)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm currently inserting PDFs as OLE Objects the following way:

```
rng.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
                                        
Set a = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddOLEObject(ClassType:="AcroExch.Document.DC", FileName:=PATH, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Anchor:=rng, Top:=0, Left:=0, Width:=842, Height:=595)
a.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionOuterMarginArea
a.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionOuterMarginArea
```

But I can't find out a way to make the ole object also cover the header. Maybe I can change the range in some way that it also includes the header?
Here is a screenshot of what it currently looks like:
[image: The yellow border shows the header which should be covered, below that is the PDF]

Comment: This should be done in VBA, since its multiple technical drawing which shall be automatically imported into the word document.